# Script Powershell to list and delete remote content folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Im working on a script to delete content of remote server's folder:

```
$Servers = Get-Content "D:\servers.txt"
$Path = "\D$\Test"
$Folders = "\\$Servers$Path"
Get-ChildItem "$Folders" -Recurse -Force | Select-object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime

Foreach ($Item in $Servers)
    {       
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$Folders" -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -Whatif
    }
```

I need first, list the content and then confirm before delete it.

I dont know if a have to use Foreach or not, if it is better use invoke-command, or invoke-command into the Foreach loop etc.

Sorry, im a totaly noob with PS :(

what is the best structure for this script ?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi again @Kristian Kanchev

This is the final script:

```
$Servers = Get-Content "D:\servers.txt"

$Folder = "\D$\Test"

foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {
Write-output `n
Write-host -ForegroundColor Green List of content of "$Folder" in "$server"
Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$Folder" -Force | Select-object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime | Out-File "D:\result.txt"
Get-Content "D:\result.txt"

}
$delete = Read-Host Delete it Y/N?
Write-output `n
    if($delete -eq "Y") {



  foreach ($Server in $Servers)
    {   
    Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$Folder" -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
    if( (Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$Folder" | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
    {
Write-Host "Files and folders deleted from \\$server\$Folder" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
    }
    }
} 
elseif ($delete -eq "N") {

Write-Host "Deletion cancelled" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
Write-output `n
}
else {
        Write-Host "Script cancelled" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor 
Black
        Write-output `n
        exit
}
```

Best regards ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Invoke-Command before `Get-ChildItem $Folders -Recurse -Force | Select-object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime | Out-File \\YOURPC\c$\Temp\result.txt`. For testing purposes I did no use it.

1. You go through the list of server.
2. You output the list to a file, so you can check.
3. You provide the script with an answer Y/N.
4. Remember to remove -WhatIf and you can add -Verbose, so you can see what was deleted just in case.

Hope the below code helps.

```
$Servers = Get-Content "C:\Temp\servers.txt"
$Path = "c$\Temp2"
$Folders = "\\$Servers\$Path"

ForEach ($server in $Servers) {

    Get-ChildItem $Folders -Recurse -Force | Select-object -Property FullName, LastWriteTime | Out-File \\YOURPC\c$\Temp\result.txt

}

$delete = Read-Host "Should the listed files in C:\Temp\result.txt be deleted Y/N?"

if($delete -eq "Y") {

    foreach ($server in $Servers) {
     Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$Folders" -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
     Write-Host "Files/Folders deleted." -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
    }
} 
elseif ($delete -eq "N") {
        Write-Host "Deletion cancelled." -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor Black
}
else {
        Write-Host "Invalid option, exiting script.." -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
        exit
}
```

Comment: Hi Kristian, sorry for the delay... Im going test it and i will let you know how it has gone. Best regards !!

Comment: Hi @Beric were you able to test?

Comment: Hi, i wrote a new answer because i could not write much text in a comment.

Comment: @Beric I saw your answer, one thing, did you try using Invoke-Command as I mentioned which should fix this issue, if not let me know and I will make a test.

Comment: I have edited the last answer, now the script works correctly :)